# Is printing NULL string defined?

Tags: c++, c, standards, undefined-behavior

Does this code have defined behaviour?

```
char *str = NULL;
printf("%s\n",str);
```

In context of C++ (98/03 and 11) and C (99) standards.

Comment: Sorry to sound so harsh, but: If you have to ask, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "null string". There's hardly such thing as a "string" to begin with (unless you mean `std::string` of course).

Comment: @KerrekSB From the standard: _"A **string** is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character."_ But yes, NULL string was an oversimplification on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

undefined behavior in C

> (C99, 7.19.6.1p8) "s If no l length modifier is present, the argument
>   shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character
>   type."

with some compilers / libc it prints `(null)` and with some other it segfaults.

(Note: in C violation of a `shall` that is not a constraint is undefined behavior, see 4.p2 "Conformance" in Standard C)

Comment: @ThiefMaster It results in undefined behavior as a consequence of the meaning of "shall" in standards in general and in C standards in particular. See the "Conformance" section at the beginning.

Comment: If you could also find the corresponding chapter in the C++ standard, that would be great.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: the C++ Standard usually does not redefine the C functions, it starts by referencing the C Standard for this reason.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh, yeah you are right. Damn, I need to open the standard more often :-D Thx

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

`printf` will dereference the pointer `str` and dereferencing a NULL pointer is UB.

Comment: Is `printf` derenferencing the pointer std part of the standard?

Comment: @codaddict don't you mean "No" as the answer to the question?

Answer (score -1):

De-referencing a `null` pointer in `C` produces `undefined behavior`, which could be catastrophic. However, most implementations simply halt execution of the program in question, usually with a segmentation fault.

Please check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_pointers)

Comment: @MS Because it is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Could you please elaborate your reason why you think this is `completely irrelevant`?

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj Because there is no dereferencing involved in the question. The question actually is whether the standard mandates that `printf` has to check for `NULL` before dereferencing (as it is currently implemented in glibc).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be But it isn't! It directly answers the question! The only thing wrong with it is that with most compilers I've tried, it prints "(null)" instead of crashing, but other than that, there is nothing irrelevant about this answer.

Comment: @MrLister And where that is required by the standard was exactly what this question was about.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be "The question actually is whether the standard mandates that printf has to check for NULL before dereferencing" - where exactly was this mentioned in the question?! The OP was whether "printf("%s\n",str);" have any undefined behavior when str is NULL! IMHO, your justification for -1 is not reasonable! Anyhow, have a nice day! :)